# pulling ID from column 1, where column 2 has multiple values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display `'id'`, `'topic_id'` where an `'id'` may have two specific values from column two, in one table. 
however, some id's have multiple values.

```
id    topic_id
1     red
2     blue
1     blue
4     purple
```

if i want to display the id's where topic_id is BOTH red and blue, what is the query?

```
select id, topic_id
from db
where topic_id='red, blue';
```

the result set is "1,2" instead of just 1, which has BOTH red and blue.

thanks!!!

Comment: Are you looking for result like `1 red blue, 2 blue, 4 purple` i.e. if multiple topic ids concat them?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the query that you want:

```
select id
from yourtable
where topic_id in ('blue', 'red')
group by id
having count(distinct topic_id) > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66321/1)

Or

```
select id
from yourtable
where topic_id in ('blue', 'red')
group by id
having count(distinct topic_id) = 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66321/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query. The nested SELECT query is going to return all IDs that have the topic_id 'blue'. It's then going to look at that list of IDs and if any of them also have a topic_id of 'red', then they will be returned in your result set.

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE topic_id ='blue')
AND topic_id = 'red';
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889ae/7/0)

Comment: This is not correct, as it will return ids that have multiple rows with the same topic_id value.

Comment: You're right - good catch. Here is an updated query that will only return an ID if it has BOTH 'red' and 'blue' topic_ids.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for result like 1 red blue, 2 blue, 4 purple i.e. if multiple topic ids concat them? If so, please try using `GROUP_CONCAT` function as below:

```
   SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(topic_id separator ' ')
   FROM db
   WHERE topic_id in ('red', 'blue')
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING count(id) = 2;
```

If you want the topic Id values separated by `comma (,)` then:

```
   SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(topic_id separator ', ')
   FROM db
   WHERE topic_id in ('red', 'blue')
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING count(id) = 2;
```